# Formatting a complex ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to produce the following ArrayPlot programmatically:

[image]

To produce the leftmost grid, I tried this:

```
GridBox[{
   {ArrayPlot[{{0, 1, 0}}]},
   {ArrayPlot[{{1, 1, 1}}]}, 
   {ArrayPlot[{{0, 0, 0}}]}}, 
  GridBoxDividers -> {"Rows" -> {{True}}, 
    "Columns" -> {{True}}}] // DisplayForm
```

I'm unsure if this can be tailored to look like I want, or if I should pursue another solution.

edit: the general formula for the plots is an ellementary cellular automaton that inverts its output if the state of its cell is 1 (black) in t-1 (the upper square). The `CellularAutomaton` function can serve as guide.

Comment: Is the ordering important? Is there a formula that generates which boxes are filled?

Comment: Your code is complicated. Try this: `ArrayPlot[{{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}]`. Now just hand-code the 3x3 matrices for each of these, map `ArrayPlot` and wrap in `Row` and you should be pretty close to done (except for some minor tweaks). This will be far easier and faster than trying to come up with a clever algorithmic/programmatic way to generate those images.

Comment: Can you post the code for the specific automaton?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you generate a `list` of 9-element lists of 0's and 1's using `CellularAutomaton`, then you can do the following:

```
GraphicsRow[
  Framed[
    ArrayPlot[
      #
      , Frame -> False
      , Axes -> False
    ]
  ] & /@ list
]
```

For instance, if

```
list = CellularAutomaton[30, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 5];
```

then the code above generates

[image]

You can add the proper gridlines by adding

```
Epilog -> {
  Line[{{1, 0}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 0}, {1, 0}}]
  , Line[{{0, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 1}}]
 }
```

for your particular version. In addition, you can format each plot the same as you see fit by modifying the `Options` sent to `ArrayPlot`.

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing from @march's answer (and non-CelluarAutomaton)...

```
pos = Subsets[{2, 4, 5, 6, 8}] /. x_Integer :> {x};
list = (Partition[#, 3] & /@ (ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, 9], 1, #] & /@ pos));

GraphicsRow[
 Framed[ArrayPlot[#, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Epilog -> {Line[{{1, 0}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 0}, {1, 0}}], 
   Line[{{0, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 1}}]}]] & /@ list, 
  ImageSize -> 1500]
```

[image]